# How to put this script in order?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a script in Javascript that scrolls down and loads a new url when it hits the bottom. Now, I want the script to wait for 30 seconds when it hits the bottom, and then load the new url.

I am quite new to Javascript, the code I have works, but I think the order or syntax is wrong.

It does scroll to the bottom but once it hits the bottom it doesn't wait for 30 sec, altough I have the wait function in the script.

This is my current script.

If someone can help me reorder it so it works as intended, or help me edit the script, would be great. Thanks.

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

function delayExecution() {
    /**
     * This function waits for 30 seconds before launching the next line of code.
     */
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Code to be executed after the delay
        console.log("Next line of code executed after 30 seconds");
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds delay
}

// Call the function to delay the execution
delayExecution();

// Function to load a new URL when scroll hits the bottom
function loadNewUrlOnScroll() {
  // Check if the scroll has reached the bottom of the page
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    // Replace the URL with the new URL
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/new-url";
  }
}

// Attach the scroll event listener to the window
window.addEventListener("scroll", loadNewUrlOnScroll);
```

I tried fixing this via AI but it made it worst, lol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

function delayExecution() {
  /**
   * This function waits for 30 seconds before launching the next line of code.
   */
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Replace the URL with the new URL
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/new-url";
  }, 30000); // 30 seconds delay
}

// Function to load a new URL when scroll hits the bottom
function loadNewUrlOnScroll() {
  // Check if the scroll has reached the bottom of the page
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    // Call the function to delay the execution
    delayExecution();
  }
}

// Attach the scroll event listener to the window
window.addEventListener("scroll", loadNewUrlOnScroll);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can I make this repeat for multiple URLS? Let's say I have 10 URLS that I want to load one after the other, with the same scroll and delay?